# Redirect all DNS requests to custom resolver in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, dns, vpn

everyone.
I am trying to **override dns resolver settings in my iOS app**.

I used **NEVPNManager** to install a **personal vpn** and then used **onDemandRules** to set specific dns servers.
So far my code **works for some domains**.
Below is my code.

When I put "*.com" in **matchDomains**, it works perfectly.

But **what I want to do** is to **redirect all dns queries** to specific dns server.
I tried empty matchDomains([]) and empty string([""]).
I also tried wildcard expression like ["*"] and ["*.*].
So far I had no success.

It's been a few days and I still can't figure it out.
Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?
Thanks in advance.

```
    let manager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()  
    manager.loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler { error in  
    if let vpnError = error {  
        print("vpn error in loading preferences : \(vpnError)")  
        return  
    }  

    if manager.protocolConfiguration == nil {  
        let myIPSec = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()  
        myIPSec.username = "username"  
        myIPSec.serverAddress = "server address"  
        myIPSec.passwordReference = self.getPersistentRef()  
        myIPSec.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.SharedSecret  
        myIPSec.sharedSecretReference = self.getPersistentRef()  
        myIPSec.useExtendedAuthentication = true  

        manager.protocolConfiguration = myIPSec  
        manager.localizedDescription = "myDNS"  

        let evaluationRule = NEEvaluateConnectionRule(matchDomains: ["*.com"], andAction: NEEvaluateConnectionRuleAction.ConnectIfNeeded)  
        evaluationRule.useDNSServers = ["XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"]  

        let onDemandRule = NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection()  
        onDemandRule.connectionRules = [evaluationRule]  
        onDemandRule.interfaceTypeMatch = NEOnDemandRuleInterfaceType.Any  

        manager.onDemandRules = [onDemandRule]  
        manager.onDemandEnabled = true  
        manager.enabled = true  

        manager.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler { error in  
            if let vpnError = error {  
                print("vpn error in saving preferences : \(vpnError)")  
                return  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hello!, are you able to achieve the result?, also the DNS server address is the address of remote server (we need to start a dns server), also do we need any other remote server to connect to VPN tunnel?, If you could help me it would be grea!

Comment: @user1068810
try this demo, https://github.com/anismansuri63/DNS-Forwarding

Answer (score 0):

I found this is buggy in even the latest iOS (10.3.1) and using NEVPNProtocolIKEv2. One moment it works, the next moment it doesn't want to start a VPN connection because it seems to misinterpret the ondemand rules and gives the error back saying the VPN profile is not enabled. I ended up with configuring the IKEv2 server (Strongswan) to push DNS settings with the "rightdns" option in /etc/ipsec.conf. This gives me the desired result of having the DNS requests redirected to a custom resolver.

Comment: Thanks for you insight, @juiced. I know this doesn't work, maybe you can share more about how you did it.

Comment: Do you use Strongswan anyway?

Comment: All I need is to change dns settings for a specific app on iOS, I didn't go through with server-side coding. That's why I used NEVPNManager to create personal vpn.

Comment: You cannot have the VPN profile, including the matchDomains rules, to be active without being able to set up a VPN connection to a VPN server.